# How to set in Perl and FCGI the POST_MAX limit

Tags: perl, cgi, fastcgi

I am looking how to set POST_MAX in Perl & FCGI. I am using the perl module CGI::Fast.

Most examples that I have found are with CGI and I dont think that it works the same way for example:

```
use strict;
use CGI;
use Fcntl qw( :DEFAULT :flock );

use constant UPLOAD_DIR     => "/usr/local/apache/data/uploads";
use constant BUFFER_SIZE    => 16_384;
use constant MAX_FILE_SIZE  => 1_048_576;       # Limit each upload to 1 MB
use constant MAX_DIR_SIZE   => 100 * 1_048_576; # Limit total uploads to 100 MB
use constant MAX_OPEN_TRIES => 100;

$CGI::DISABLE_UPLOADS   = 0;
$CGI::POST_MAX          = MAX_FILE_SIZE;

my $q = new CGI;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CGI::Fast`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aFast) is a subclass of the CGI object created by [`CGI.pm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI).

Therefore, you can use the features in CGI, namely [`Avoiding DOS Attacks`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Avoiding-Denial-of-Service-Attacks):

> `$CGI::POST_MAX`
>
> If set to a non-negative integer, this variable puts a ceiling on the size of POSTings, in bytes. If CGI.pm detects a POST that is greater than the ceiling, it will immediately exit with an error message. This value will affect both ordinary POSTs and multipart POSTs, meaning that it limits the maximum size of file uploads as well. You should set this to a reasonably high value, such as 1 megabyte.
>
> `$CGI::DISABLE_UPLOADS`
>
> If set to a non-zero value, this will disable file uploads completely. Other fill-out form values will work as usual.